# Shell script that copies configuration and dotfiles to repository

Tags: bash, shell

A while ago I had the idea to store all the important configuration and dotfiles from my system in a Git repository. That saved me a few months ago: My harddrive died, but I could get back to work with Ubuntu and that repository quickly.

Only problem: I maintained that repo by manually copying the files from the various directories to the repo directory. That’s what I wrote the shell script for.

**What does the script do?**

1. Checks whether the command is executed from within the root of a git repository
2. Detects which OS it’s operating on (Windows, Linux or OS X) and saves that information in a variable `OS`
3. Assigns variables for certain *tool groups* (like Bash, Git, etc.) and creates the target directories in the repo if they don’t exist
4. Copies file by file to these destinations

**Notes:**

- Currently, I separate the files on a per-OS basis. This is probably unnecessary and even a hinderance. I’d like to here your opinion here
- The script currently does not use any Bash >4 features, because besides Ubuntu I mainly work on Windows. I use Git Bash there which only has version 3 bundled.
- I also wrote a short article about this script: [Backup configuration and dotfiles with Git and a shell script](http://hey.kleinfreund.de/en/2015/05/backup-configuration-and-dotfiles-with-git-and-a-shell-script/)
- If you’re interested in current/updated versions, check out the script in the repo: [get-dotfiles.sh](https://github.com/kleinfreund/dotfiles/blob/master/get-dotfiles.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

################################################################################
#
# Shell script to copy important configuration files from the current
# environment to this repository.
#
################################################################################

# Exit as soon as a command fails
set -e

# Accessing an empty variable will yield an error
set -u

# Assume the working directory is the path to the dotfiles repository
REPO_PATH="$PWD/"

# Abort mission when we’re not in a git repository
if [[ ! -d .git ]] || ! git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Not a git repository."
    exit 1
fi



# Detect OS (OS X, Linux or Windows)
if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then
    echo "Detected system: OS X"

    OS="osx/"

    ST_DIR="$HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/"
elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 5)" = "Linux" ]; then
    echo "Detected system: Linux"

    OS="linux/"

    ST_DIR="$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/"
elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 10)" = "MINGW32_NT" ]; then
    echo "Detected system: Windows"

    OS="win/"

    ST_DIR="$HOME/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/"
    NPM_DIR="$HOME/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/npm/"
fi

# Adjust destination paths so the files are separated by OS
BASH_DEST="${REPO_PATH}${OS}bash/"
GIT_DEST="${REPO_PATH}${OS}git/"
NPM_DEST="${REPO_PATH}${OS}npm/"
RUBY_DEST="${REPO_PATH}${OS}ruby/"
ST_DEST="${REPO_PATH}${OS}sublime-text/"

declare -a destinations=($BASH_DEST $GIT_DEST $NPM_DEST $RUBY_DEST $ST_DEST)

for dest in "${destinations[@]}"; do
    mkdir -p "$dest"
done



# Bash
cp "$HOME/.bashrc" "$BASH_DEST"
cp "$HOME/.bash_aliases" "$BASH_DEST"

# Git
cp "$HOME/.gitignore_global" "$GIT_DEST"
cp "$HOME/.gitconfig" "$GIT_DEST"

# Node.js/npm
cp "${NPM_DIR}.npmrc" "$NPM_DEST"

# Ruby/RubyGems
cp "$HOME/.gemrc" "$RUBY_DEST"

# Sublime Text
cp "${ST_DIR}Preferences.sublime-settings" "$ST_DEST"
cp "${ST_DIR}Markdown.sublime-settings" "$ST_DEST"
cp "${ST_DIR}YAML.sublime-settings" "$ST_DEST"
cp "${ST_DIR}Package Control.sublime-settings" "$ST_DEST"
cp "${ST_DIR}For Loop (range).sublime-snippet" "$ST_DEST"
cp "${ST_DIR}Fraction (TeX).sublime-snippet" "$ST_DEST"



# OS specific copy operations
if [ "$OS" = "osx/" ]; then
    echo "Nothing here."
elif [ "$OS" = "linux/" ]; then
    cp "${ST_DIR}Default (Linux).sublime-keymap" "$ST_DEST"
elif [ "$OS" = "windows/" ]; then
    cp "${ST_DIR}Default (Windows).sublime-keymap" "$ST_DEST"
fi

echo "Completed."
```

*(Shell scripts are new terrain for me, I probably made some faulty assumptions. Still, don’t have mercy.)*

Comment: This script looks reasonable. I'd just suggest that a makefile might be useful for this kind of thing too, especially if you want to make the copying conditional on timestamps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty nicely written. I have a couple of tips to improve it though.

#### Don't include trailing `/` in path variables

Although there's absolutely nothing wrong with this:

> ```
> REPO_PATH="$PWD/"
> # ...
> OS="osx/"
> # ...
> BASH_DEST="${REPO_PATH}${OS}bash/"
> ```

In my experience, not including the trailing slash is typically more ergonomic, and sometimes even less error-prone:

- You might have a function that's expecting the trailing slash, and some callers might forget to append it correctly, and there's no reasonable way to enforce at "compile time".
- When I see concatenated path-like variables like `$REPO_PATH${OS}bash` I'm always suspicious if the caller added the slash or not.
  It makes me constantly look over my shoulders and re-check all uses.

Consider this alternative:

```
REPO_PATH=$PWD
# ...
OS=osx
# ...
BASH_DEST="$REPO_PATH/$OS/bash"
```

Here, I *know* that `"$REPO_PATH/$OS/bash"` will be definitely close to what I expect,
and no need to worry about forgotten slashes anywhere.
I also know it's a path,
which is less obvious in the case of the original.

#### Don't execute the same thing repeatedly

When you detect the OS,
the script might execute `uname` 3 times.
It would be better to run it once and save in a variable.

#### Avoid `expr`

`expr` is archaic. Usually there are better solutions.
You could also simplify the OS detection conditions using `[[` instead:

```
uname=$(uname -s)   

# Detect OS (OS X, Linux or Windows)
if [[ $uname = Darwin ]]; then
    echo "Detected system: OS X"
    OS=osx
    ST_DIR="$HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/"
elif [[ $uname == *Linux* ]]; then
    echo "Detected system: Linux"    
    OS=linux
    ST_DIR="$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/"
elif [[ $uname == *MINGW32_NT* ]]; then
    echo "Detected system: Windows"   
    OS=win
    ST_DIR="$HOME/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/"
    NPM_DIR="$HOME/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/npm/"
fi
```

#### Quote paths that may contain spaces

It's not obvious that these paths will never contain spaces:

> ```
> declare -a destinations=($BASH_DEST $GIT_DEST $NPM_DEST $RUBY_DEST $ST_DEST)
> ```

It's better to be safe, and put double-quotes around each.

#### More careful error handling

If you couldn't detect the OS, I suggest to print a warning and exit.

#### Use `case` for switches

The final OS-specific operations could be written a bit cleaner using a `case` statement.

Comment: Very nice, thank you, janos. I also added an if-statement for the NPM and ST copy commands to check whether `$NPM_DIR` and `$ST_DIR` exist.